# CurrentUser / ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, owin

I need some help.  How can I get access to the current authenticated user/ClaimsPrincipal.  In the old times, I would use HttpContext.Current, but that seems wrong somehow now.

Answer (score 11):

With OWIN, the user can be found off of the OWIN context's Authentication.User property.

```
OwinContext context = Request.GetOwinContext();
ClaimsPrinicipal user = context.Authentication.User;
// do stuff with user.
```

Brock Allen has a [post on using cookie authentication with OWIN](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/).

Comment: If you've added to the user's profile how can you access the User object with all the profile information?  Or another way of asking it is your method gets a 'ClaimsPrincipal' object.  How can I get an 'IdentityUser' object fully hydrated?  I know I can get it via UserManager, but I don't want to call that method every time I need the user.    Is that the only way?

Answer (score 3):

If your using Web Api 2, you should now be using `RequestContext.Principal` for any of your identity inspection/assignment needs.

Answer (score 0):

In what context do you want to access it? I'll answer from the perspective of a Web API service that issues OAuth2 tokens, since that's what I just happened to program. If that's not your scenario, please give us your specifics.

If you want the authenticated user so you can issue a token, and you've overridden `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`, you'll find it in `context.Request.User`, where `context` is the parameter to the overridden method.

In classes that inherit from `ApiController` (in ASP.NET Web API), you can inspect `this.User`. That will be the `ClaimsPrincipal` you put in the OAuth2 token.